# Создать пирамиду в виде чисел в обратном порядке. Пользователь вводит число

Tags: javascript

Javascript. Создать пирамиду в виде чисел в обратном порядке. Пользователь вводит число. К примеру введено 5, первый ряд 5, второй ряд 5 4, третий - 5 4 3 и т.д.

> 5
>     54
>     543
>     5432
>     54321

```
function onSubmit()
{
    var val = document.getElementById('table').value;

    for (var i = val; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (var j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
            document.write(j);
        }
        document.write('<br>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Что именно у Вас не получается? Покажите Ваш код.

Comment: Какое поведение ожидается, если пользователь вводит двузначное число?

Comment: Просто пробелы меду числами поставить, чтобы можно было понять, что происходит, если пользователь вводит двузначный код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените внутренний цикл с

```
for (var j = i; j >= 1; j--)
```

на

```
for (var j = val; j >= i; j--)
```

Тогда j будет соответствовать задаче: каждая строка будет начинаться с введённого числа и будет длиной в номер строки.